# Getting null in values from Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-5

I am using promises. This is in continuation to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127919/return-promises-instead-of-async)

The issue I am having is that in response, i.e. an array of objects is having null values. I will try to explain this

1. First I get the userId
2. Get user whishlist products from the userId
3. Then using userId I get stores/shop list
4. Then I iterate over store list and call another API to check if this store is user favourite store.
5. Then I get the products of each store and append in an object and return.

   ```
   function getStoresList(context) {
       const userID = common.getUserID(context)
       let userWishListProd = []

       return userID
           .then(uid => Wishlist.getUserWishlistProducts(uid).then((products) => {
               userWishListProd = products.data.map(product => +product.id)
               return uid
           }))
           .then(uid => api.getOfficialStoresList(uid).then((response) => {
                   if (!response.data) {
                       const raw = JSON.stringify(response)
                       return []
                   }

                   const shops = response.data
                   return Promise.all(
                           shops.map((shop) => {
                               const id = shop.shop_id
                               const shopobj = {
                                   id,
                                   name: shop.shop_name,
                               }
                               return favAPI.checkFavourite(uid, id)
                                   .then((favData) => {
                                       shopobj.is_fave_shop = favData

                                       // Fetch the products of shop
                                       return getProductList(id, uid)
                                           .then((responsedata) => {
                                               shopobj.products = responsedata.data.products.map(product => ({
                                                   id: product.id,
                                                   name: product.name,
                                                   is_wishlist: userWishListProd.indexOf(product.id) > -1,
                                               }))
                                               return shopobj
                                           })
                                           .catch(() => {})
                                   })
                                   .catch(err => console.error(err))
                           }))
                       .then(responses => responses)
                       .catch(err => console.log(err))
               })
               .catch(() => {}))
           .catch()
   }
   ```

The response I get is

```
[{
        "id": 1001,
        "name": "Gaurdian Store",
        "is_fave_shop": "0",
        "products": [{
            "id": 14285912,
            "name": "Sofra Cream",
            "is_wishlist": false
        }]
    },
    null,
    null,
    {
        "id": 1002,
        "name": "decolite",
        "is_fave_shop": "1",
        "products": [{
            "id": 14285912,
            "name": "Denca SPF",
            "is_wishlist": false
        }]
    }
]
```

The actual store are coming as 4 but instead of it null gets appended. What is wrong I am doing with Promises here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have to do with your `.catch(() => {})` and `.catch(err => console.error(err))` invocations. If one promise in your loop has an error, it will be transformed to an `undefined` value (optionally being reported before), so that `Promise.all` will fulfill with an array that might contain `undefined` values. If you `JSON.stringify` that, you'll get `null` at those indices.

Drop the `.catch(() => {})` statements that do nothing (or replace them with logging ones), and check your error logs.

Comment: The `getProductList` call is getting 503 sometimes , I catched it and hence resulting in undefined I guess.

Comment: Ah, good to have my guess confirmed :-) Is there any problem left? If not, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you debug your code? 
I would debug on Chrome and add some break points on the code to see what the actual response is.

Comment: I am using this in Nodejs, so I put console just after I get shops, I get count 4 with all data, and when I put console in response, I get count 4 but with some null values.

Comment: I would log to the last two catch on your code. To make sure is not failing there